# Excel to create task in Outlook

Tags: vba, excel, outlook

I am relatively new to VBA and so I'm sure this is a basic mistake that I am making!

A1 contains valid date, A2 contains task information, A3 contains number of days before A1 date to trigger task reminder.

The problem is when I put =addtotasks(A1,A2,A3)

It just comes up with #NAME?

I have enabled the Microsoft Outlook 14.0 Object Library in the references.

I am based in the UK telling you for dates purposes.

This is the following code. I have included some extra code for setting a remainder only on a business day.

```
'Function NextBusinessDay(dateFrom As Date, _
  Optional daysAhead As Long = 1) As Date
 Dim currentDate As Date
 Dim nextDate As Date

' convert neg to pos
 If daysAhead < 0 Then
  daysAhead = Abs(daysAhead)
End If

' determine next date
 currentDate = dateFrom
 nextDate = DateAdd("d", daysAhead, currentDate)

 ' is next date a weekend day?
  Select Case Weekday(nextDate, vbUseSystemDayOfWeek)
Case vbSunday
nextDate = DateAdd("d", 1, nextDate)
 Case vbSaturday
 nextDate = DateAdd("d", 2, nextDate)
  End Select

  NextBusinessDay = CDate(Int(nextDate))


End Function

Dim bWeStartedOutlook As Boolean

Function AddToTasks(strDate As String, strText As String, DaysOut As Integer) As Boolean
' Adds a task reminder to Outlook Tasks a specific number of days before the date specified
' Returns TRUE if successful ' Will not trigger OMG because no protected properties are accessed
'
' Usage:
' =AddToTasks("12/31/2008", "Something to remember", 30)
' or:
' =AddToTasks(A1, A2, A3)
' where A1 contains valid date, A2 contains task information, A3 contains number of days before A1 date to trigger task reminder '
' can also be used in VBA :
'If AddToTasks("12/31/2008", "Christmas shopping", 30) Then
'  MsgBox "ok!"
'End If
Dim intDaysBack As Integer
Dim dteDate As Date
Dim olApp As Object 'Outlook.Application
Dim objTask As Object ' Outlook.TaskItem
' make sure all fields were filled in
If (Not IsDate(strDate)) Or (strText = "") Or (DaysOut <= 0) Then
AddToTasks = False
GoTo ExitProc
End If
' We want the task reminder a certain number of days BEFORE the due date
' ex: if DaysOut = 120, then we want the due date to be -120 before the date specified
' we need to pass -120 to the NextBusinessDay function, so to go from 120 to -120,
' we subtract double the number (240) from the number provided (120).
' 120 - (120 * 2); 120 - 240 = -120
intDaysBack = DaysOut - (DaysOut * 2)

dteDate = NextBusinessDay(CDate(strDate), intDaysBack)

On Error Resume Next
   Set olApp = GetOutlookApp
On Error GoTo 0

If Not olApp Is Nothing Then
   Set objTask = olApp.CreateItem(3)   ' task item

   With objTask
    .StartDate = dteDate
    .Subject = strText & ", due on: " & strDate
    .ReminderSet = True
    .Save
   End With

Else
   AddToTasks = False
   GoTo ExitProc
End If

   ' if we got this far, it must have worked
AddToTasks = True

ExitProc:
If bWeStartedOutlook Then
   olApp.Quit
End If
Set olApp = Nothing
Set objTask = Nothing
End Function

Function GetOutlookApp() As Object

On Error Resume Next
   Set GetOutlookApp = GetObject(, "Outlook.Application")
   If Err.Number <> 0 Then
    Set GetOutlookApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    bWeStartedOutlook = True
   End If
On Error GoTo 0

End Function
```

---

I have taken this code from this website, by the way: 
http://www.jpsoftwaretech.com/get-previous-business-day-in-vba/

Comment: BirdsView: Have you pasted the code in a module?

Comment: Did you try stepping through the code?

Comment: Not exactly... do you mean "Compile VBAProject"? It gets "stuck" on "If daysAhead < 0 Then" --> Compile error: Invalid outside procedure - ignore this... still going.

Comment: Nope. You need to debug the code by stepping through it by pressing F8

Comment: OK - it skips right to the last function (getoutlookapp) - it doesn't even highlight the first line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The #Name? error happens when you reference a function or variable unknown to the program. It's not sure where this function resides. Try using the "fx" button next to the formula bar and selecting user defined functions, it should be listed there.

My guess is you created this function in a different work book probably the personal.xlsb.

In order to use user defined functions you have to reference the full path to them. Try reading the last paragraph here:

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/creating-custom-functions-HA001111701.aspx

Comment: Good idea - yes I had: =PERSONAL.XLSB!AddToTasks(A1,A2,A3)

Comment: I now have the following error: Compile error: ByRef argument type mismatch it highlights "intDaysBack)" on the line: dteDate = NextBusinessDay(CDate(strDate), intDaysBack)

Comment: Try adding "ByVal" to your next business day function day like this:   Function NextBusinessDay(dateFrom As Date, _
  Optional ByVal daysAhead As Long = 1) As Date

Comment: YES! it worked - thank you. I had to move Dim bWeStartedOutlook As Boolean - next to the other 'Dims'.

Comment: np, happy I could help